# How to specify Replace function in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Replace function in SQL query, it is working in access sql query design mode but not working in access VBA. Throwing expected end of statement. I tried all the ways but not working. **CM** column has a string like this **;#WR_1;#WR_2;#WR_3;#WR_4;#** and I'm trying to get value WR_2 where ever the string occurs in **CM** column

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM WT_table " & _
"WHERE [CM] IS NOT NULL " & _
"AND (';' & Replace([CM], '#', "") & ';') Like '*;WR_2;*'; ;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the second semi-colon (`;`) from the end of the last line - you have two of them, making it appear that there are multiple statements to be executed.

```
"AND (';' & Replace([CM], '#', "") & ';') Like '*;WR_2;*';"
```

In addition, as pointed out by simoco, you have a pair of double-quotes in your `Replace` function.  I'm not certain whether you mean to have two single-quotes or not, but this would be the right code to use in that case:

```
"AND (';' & Replace([CM], '#', '') & ';') Like '*;WR_2;*';"
```

Comment: No luck. saying syntax error in string in query expression **[CM] IS NOT NULL AND (';' & Replace([CM], '#', "") & ';') Like '*;WR_2;*'**

Comment: I have just made an edit following another user comment to also reflect that you have two double-quotes in the last line, where you possibly mean two single-quotes.